# Need to find a solution on Batch processing of copying set of file with same name to other location with limit in count

Tags: batch-file

Newbie in bat file coding. Need solution for below problem.

I've a 10,000 files are coming in batch process. In every file name there was two files (one is pdf and another is txt file).
e.g.

```
File2.pdf
File1.pdf
File2.txt 
File1.txt
```

like above the file reaches folder. i need copy a set files (same named files; no random files) to another location from source. and i need to limit the transaction 500 files first and give some sleep time and do next transfer of 500 until to complete all 10000.
this is needed because if i copy all 10000 at same time the application which loading inside get struck or take long time to process.

appreciate if you can help on this.....

Comment: `for %%f in (*) do call :copy_one_file "%~f"` and then in `:copy_one_file` count and sleep if needed.

Comment: Karthick Muthu, 500+500 ≠ 10,000. 500+500=1,000 :D

Comment: @Suda - He's saying that the script needs to process 500 at a time. 20 iterations are expected.

Comment: What have you tried, where are you stuck? This is not the place to request code for free! Please take the [tour] and learn [ask] here!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `for /f` processes dir output one at time.
`set /a` counts and calculates the remainder of `count / chunk`
If the remainder is 0 we have a multiple of `chunk(500)` and
use the timeout command to wait for `delay(30)` seconds.

Adapt the source(Src) and destination(Dst) variables to your environment.

```
:: Q:\Test\2018\06\02\SO_50654344.cmd
@Echo off&SetLocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
set "Src=C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\TestCode\input\"
Set "Dst=C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\TestCode\output\"
Set "Ext=*.*"

Set Chunk=10
Set Delay=10
Pushd "%Src%"
Set Cnt=1
For /F "delims=" %%F in ('Dir /B /ON %Ext%') Do (
   Set /A "Cnt+=1,PauseNow=Cnt%%Chunk"
   if !PauseNow!==0 Timeout %Delay%
   xcopy "%%~fF" "%Dst%"
)
PopD
```

Comment: Thank you .. I did coded using your samples.. this really helped me thanks:-)

Comment: There is no need for an intermediate file, you just have to set variables right in my answer.

Comment: Yes above works absolutely fine... Ive just amended my old code. This is fine to replace my old one now.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all your time to solve my problem. At last I Think i found solution to the problem.

Below code serves my purpose. I've taken the list of files in folder to  text file first and i start reading one by one and increase count by 1 for each read.

this works

```
@Echo off&SetLocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion

dir C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\TestCode\input\*.* /B /O:N >>C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\TestCode\test.txt

Set Delay=10
Set Cnt=1
set Chunk=10

for /F "tokens=*" %%A in (C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\TestCode\test.txt) do (
Set /A "Cnt+=1,PauseNow=Cnt%%Chunk"
if !PauseNow!==0 Timeout %Delay%
xcopy "C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\TestCode\input\%%A" "C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\TestCode\output"
)

del C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\TestCode\test.txt

pause
```

I sort the text file before processing it which gives me the exact order file to be processed.

thanks for sharing your idea's which helped me to drive to this!!!!!!!